# Changes made to Flex Builder project not being reflected in Firefox/IE

Tags: flash, firefox, apache-flex, flexbuilder

I've been having problems with the flash debug player in Firefox and IE recently, as it won't update when changes are made to the code.

Chrome seems to be working fine for me, any changes made get reflected there, although I believe a co-worker is having the same problem I am having with Chrome, where his Firefox is working fine.

Things I've tried so far:

- Cleared the browser cache.
- Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
- Uninstall/re-install of the flash debug player for Firefox.
- Deleted the Flex Builder workspace and re-imported all projects.

Haven't tried re-installing Flex Builder yet.

Using Flex Builder 3 with Flex 3.6.0, Firefox 37.0.2, and Flash debug player v17.

Given that it's working alright in Chrome, it's not too big of a problem at the moment, but it would be good to fix whatever the problem is in case the same thing happens to Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried using release build. Is it working fine?

Comment: It's quite a large project with mulitple swf files, so I tried doing a release build on both the main swf, and our preloader swf. No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, I managed to fix it by deleting the browsing history from Internet Explorer. It could have just been an amazing coincidence, but Firefox and IE started picking up changes again right after deleting the history.